How can a smart contract listen to on-chain events?
I understand that smart contracts can emit events, but I'm curious if there's a way for a smart contract to listen to on-chain events and react to them. Is it possible for a smart contract to monitor events emitted by other contracts or take action when certain events occur on-chain?

Short answer No. Smart contracts can't listen to events, it is more like a way for contracts to communicate with the "outside world".
You can create a program that listens to events (offchain) and then pushes the data into a contract (onchain).
The contract's storage can then be read onchain by your contract.
